# É possível rodar o mesmo site em domínios diferentes

Tags: php, dns

Tenho meu site e tenho 3 domínios diferentes.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de rodar a mesmo site nesses domínios.

Comment: Claro que é possível é só você subir os mesmos arquivos para outros ftp's

Comment: Ou apontar os três domínios para a mesma pasta.

Answer (score 5):

Sim tem como. **Mas não faça isso.**

### Porque não utilizar o "mesmo site" em vários domínios?

Por conta da indexação e das demais regras do Google.

Isso pois, o Google trata de maneira rigorosa **conteúdos duplicados** na internet,  apontamentos incorretos e páginas/conteúdos inexistentes (HTTP 404) ou a duplicação de conteúdo.

---

### Qual a maneira correta de fazer isso?

#### Redirecionamento permanente: HTTP 301

Resumindo o que isso significa: você está dizendo que, toda vez que um usuário acessar `www.seusite.com.br` você quer redirecionar ele para `www.seusiteoficial.com.br` de maneira *PERMANENTE*.

> Google recomenda usar o redirecionamento HTTP 301 para alterar a URL de uma página que é apresentada nos resultados da busca evitando assim o HTTP 404

**Então ficaria assim:** quando o usuário entrar nos sites:

- www.site1.com.br
- www.site2.com.br
- www.site3.com.br

Ele será redirecionado para:

- www.sitecorreto.com.br

Essa é a maneira correta.

---

### Como eu faço isso?

Há diversas opções:

- `.htaccess` (Apache `mod_rewrite`)
- `VirtualHost`
- Redirecionamento da sua própria aplicação/framework
- Painel da sua hospedagem: Cpanel/Plesk

---

### Exemplo com `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / http://www.seusiteoficial.com.br/
```

Esse `.htaccess` deve ser colocado **na raiz de cada site/domínio** seu.

---

### Recomendo

- **Em Hospedagem compartilhada:** redirecionamento pelo painel (Cpanel/Plesk)
- **Cloud/VPS:** redirecionamento pelo `<VirtualHost>` do Apache ou através de uma configuração similar no Nginx ou HHVM.

Comment: Excelente explicação, não limitou-se a responder apenas a dúvida mas sugeriu algo melhor!

Comment: @Filipe obrigado!

Comment: Qual URL aparece no browser do usuário após o redirecionamento? *site1.com.br* ou *siteoficial.com.br*??

Estou querendo algo semelhante. Tenho vários domínios e eles devem apontar para uma mesma pasta ftp onde tem um modelo desses sites. Mas quero saber se nesse redirecionamento a URL na barra de endereços PERMANECE a que foi digitada pelo usuário e se é possível passar algum parâmetro, ex: id=1.

Quando o usuário acessar *site1.com* a aplicação deve se conectar a API que contém as configurações daquele site, se acessa *site2.com* a aplicação se conectaria em outra API e assim por diante.

Comment: A resposta é antiga mas ficou uma dúvida. Se eu tenho uma versão do site em inglês num domínio `.com` e outra em português num domínio `.com.br` (mesmo código, só com conteúdo traduzido), o Google entende essa diferença ou também considera como duplicado?

Answer (score 1):

Depende a locaweb tem muitas falhas(ao menos comigo teve) porém essa opção existe.

Registro de Dominio >AlterarDominio > aqui tem um opção  'alterar endereço do navegador'

Verifique no seu serviço de hospedagem se existe algo parecido.

Att

Answer (score 0):

A empresa que cadastrou os seus domínios provavelmente passou a dispor para você um painel administrativo onde é possível configurar o funcionamento destes.

Dentre as configurações você pode escolher opções, como por exemplo redirecionar varios domínios para um unico domínio principal ou redirecionar todos para o mesmo endereço de IP. Assim todos entram no mesmo site usando apenas um FTP.

Em caso de duvida sobre como fazer isso, eu recomendo entrar em contato com a empresa que contratou os domínios, pois o passo a passo para configurar pode mudar de um painel para outro.